# JBoss JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment sqljdbc4.jar

Tags: java, jboss

We have a JBoss installation running for a couple of months.
Now JBoss doesn't start anymore also not on other machines within the domain.
Also if we restore the previously working version it does not start again.
We disable the firewall, VirusScan etc. - no solution for.
The restored snapshow is a week old and worked for the whole week but not anymore.
So really a miracle what happened...

```
> 00:25:37,740 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
00:25:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
00:25:38,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: Test EAP 6.4.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-15) starting
00:25:39,318 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) JBAS011618: There is no resource matching the expiry-address jms.queue.ExpiryQueue for the address-settings #, expired messages from destinations matching this address-setting will be lost!
00:25:39,323 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment test.ear
00:25:39,324 WARN  [org.jboss.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) JBAS011619: There is no resource matching the dead-letter-address jms.queue.DLQ for the address-settings #, undelivered messages from destinations matching this address-setting will be lost!
00:25:39,332 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment sqljdbc4.jar
00:25:39,356 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO Version 3.0.12.GA-redhat-1
00:25:39,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
00:25:39,374 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.12.GA-redhat-1
00:25:39,499 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.4.Final-redhat-1
00:25:39,414 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("console-handler" => "CONSOLE")
]) - failure description: "JBAS014802: Cannot resolve expression '${com.test.loglevelRoot}'"
00:25:39,511 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("console-handler" => "CONSOLE")
]) - failure description: "JBAS014802: Cannot resolve expression '${com.test.loglevelRoot}'"
00:25:39,531 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("logger" => "com")
]) - failure description: "JBAS014802: Cannot resolve expression '${com.test.loglevelRoot}'"
```

Maybe somebody has an idea what happened here?

Regards,
Andre

Comment: *Cannot resolve expression '${com.test.loglevelRoot}'"* Looks like you miss to declare the variable `com.test.loglevelRoot`

Comment: Also using an Alpha version of EAP 6.4 is quite risky I would say